# Nifi UpdateRecord processor changes the output of flow file into only nulls

Tags: apache-nifi, avro

I have two avro-binary types of flow files in Nifi and their content is:

Flow file one:

```
[ {
"DepartmentID" : "Undefined",
"Name" : "Non Billable",
} ]
```

Flow file two:

```
[ {
"DepartmentID" : "Null",
"Name" : "Tax",
} ]
```

I am using UpdateRecord processor to add a key:value (tenantId) in the same file for which I am using below avro schema:

```
{
"name": "nifi",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
{ "name": "TenantId", "type": ["null","string"] },
{ "name": "DepartmentId", "type": ["null","string"] },
{ "name": "Name", "type": ["null","string"] }
]
}
```

I am using literal value replacement value strategy and getting TenantId from previous processors. So far, this is a success and tenantId is appended. However, as a result, the DepartmentId changes to null for BOTH the files. Where I can ensure that the DepartmentId's values are not changed because based on these values, I have to route the "undefined" file for further processing (such as convert undefined string to its ID format by getting value from my database)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.